# .NET reference not available in my project (Class Library). Getting compiler error "mismatch between processor architecture"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017

I have a Class Library which needs the `.NET` reference to work as it utilizes a lot of `System` APIs but I am unable to add the reference from the `Add References` dialogue box. The `.NET` reference isn't available under `Assemblies` in the `Reference Manager`.

This is how my project looks like and I get the following error when I build this project:

`There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\\mscorlib.dll", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.`

[image]

Following is the screenshot of my Reference Manager

[image]

I want the `.NET` reference as attached to the image below.Any idea how can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: What reference?

Comment: `.NET` reference

Comment: required screenshots?

Comment: Can you please specify the specific reference you are having issues with?

Comment: @Chrille `.NET` reference

Comment: What is ".NET reference"? A .NET class library should have the requisite system and similar references, you don't add a reference to ".NET". Can you be specific exactly what it is you want to add? Also, why do you need to add anything, show code that doesn't compile and tell us what you tried to add in order to fix that.

Comment: Please view the image I added. I need this `.NET` reference

Comment: What references do you have? What kind of project are you having problems with? What kind of project did you get that screenshot from?

Comment: I have references to other projects. As attached in the question, I am missing this .NET reference which I had previously
It is a class library. Web project

Comment: Maybe you can post some errors you get because of the missing reference?

Comment: @Chrille I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to this question.

To resolve the process architecture mismatch issue, I followed the following steps :

First I uninstalled the `nuget` packages in my project.

Then I opened the properties of my project. Left-click your project and open `Properties`.

Click on `Library` in the left panel and under `Targets` click `Change`. If the `.NET Framework` is checked, uncheck it and save by clicking `Ok`.

Then re-install the `nuget` packages and build again. It worked like a charm. It seems that Visual Studio 2017 automatically adds the `.NET` reference. I believe its a bug in VS 2017

Answer (score 0):

To add one of the many .NET libraries, right-click on "References" and select "Add Reference".

The dialog that opens up has a menu on the left, and the .NET libraries can be found under "Assemblies" -> "Framework".

For example, `System.Web.Services`. (There is no ".NET reference" per se... it is divided into many assemblies).

[image: Add Reference]

Comment: There are no references available under Assemblies

Comment: Can you share your Reference Manager screenshot?